# Multiple levels of expansion of space?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, space-expansion, order-of-magnitude, structure-formation

[image: Princeton Universe Map]

It can easily be seen from the plot that there are at least 3 gaps between objects in the large, there is the gap between the planets and the moons, and between the planets and stars, and between stars and galaxies.

If we assume that the universe began small then nine if these spaces could exist, which means that the universe must have expanded at at least 3 different scales, if there was only one scale of the universe that was expanding then there would be only two sizes of objects, one small and one big with one gap in between?

Why do physicists still think there is only one expansion scale?

Comment: Please edit the question to get rid of the giant graphic. Please don't cut and paste on the internet without crediting the author. It's rude. *Why do physicists still think there is only one expansion scale?* This sounds like you've misunderstood something.

Comment: You can't deduce anything about cosmological expansion from the structure of the solar system & galaxy.

Comment: @BenCrowell: The alt text of the image “Princeton Universe Map” is sort of attribution,  but the actual publication is [*A map of the universe*](https://doi.org/10.1086/428890).

Comment: @Halsey: That is untrue if: 1) the universe started small 2) the empty space was produced by expansion 3) if the expansion occured at the very large... Then there is no possibility for gravity to compress things together into stars and planets as there is no space for them to be compressed together.

Comment: @Crowell: If the universe started small, and expansion happened only at the very large then where was the space for gravity to compress things together? Actually, it is the current understanding of universal development that is actually not possibly true!

Comment: @BenCrowell: Sorry that I did not write up a full accreditation, I thought that for an internet discussion it would be acceptable! Sorry, will write more in future!

Answer (score 1):

> It can easily be seen from the plot that there are at least 3 gaps between objects in the large, there is the gap between the planets and the moons, and between the planets and stars, and between stars and galaxies.

First of all, that's just a picture. It does not correctly represent the distance scales.

I don't think we can consider the distance between planets and moon or planets and stars as "gap". It's just how these structures are formed.

Earth-Moon distance $1.245 \times 10^{-8} pc$

Earth - Sun distance $4.848 \times 10^{-6} pc$

Earth – Galactic Center distance $8 \times 10^3 pc$

However, our distance to other much distant objects are in order of $10^{6} - 10^{8} pc$ (sometimes even more or less)

There are indeed large voids between galaxy superclusters ( such as [KBC void](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KBC_Void)). You can look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_(astronomy)#Galactic_formation_and_evolution_models) to see how these voids are formed.

> If we assume that the universe began small then nine if these spaces could exist, which means that the universe must have expanded at least 3 different scales,

What do you mean by "if these spaces could exist" ? There should, of course some distances between such objects/systems. These distances occur naturally we don't need any kind of expansion to explain such a thing.

And most importantly we do not observe such expansion between planets and stars (scales of $10^{-6}pc$).

The expansion scale is approximately $10 ^{8} pc$ where the universe is assumed to be homogeneous and isotropic. In this case, the expansion must conserve this homogeneity and isotropy at all times. This leads to famous the Hubble Law, which is also confirmed by the observations.

We dont need an expansion law to describe the galaxy/solar system structures.

Comment: Agreed, the plot shows that expansion of space is logarithmic, with the rate of expansion determined by the size of space at all scales.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but o am still confused! You say that the space between stars and planets "occurs naturally", but in my mind the only two ways for it to occur naturally are that it began big at the start of time, or it expanded at different scales rather than just the very large? Are there any other ways?

Comment: I think this fits better: Each scale of the universe is expanding in order, from the very small to the very large. All the different scales of the atoms expanded first, to the point that the very small are now fully disconnected from each other, giving quantum mechanics and particles which get more fixed and unchanging the smaller they get because they become more disconnected. The final 3 scales, seen on the plot are in the process of disconnecting, which creates dynamic changing normal space. The expansion of the scale above also compresses the layer below, which is gravity.

Comment: @OzOz I dont understand why you think that we need some sort of "expansion " to understand the solar system. Look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_System#Formation_and_evolution. ( Or any planetary system)

Comment: In the expansion of the universe the objects are not actually moving but space is expanding at it kind of carries the galaxies with it. This expansion happens in the order of $10^{8}pc$ level. However, our distance to sun is $10^{-6}pc$. Theres no way that we can "feel" (measure /observe) this expansion by looking at the solar system, or in any other system in such scales. This means that the expansion of the universe cannot effect such small scales.

Comment: @Ozoz How can atoms expand ? I am having some trouble to understand the logic behind your idea. Expansion of the universe shapes the superclusters and maybe galaxy formations but it does not have any effect on small scales such as galaxy scale or smaller than that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100868/discussion-between-ozoz-and-reign).

Comment: Sorry, it will not let me post in the chat, this happened before and resolved itself later, but still not working...

Comment: Thanks for the discussion! This formation of the solar system is of course we'll described... But it starts with a system that contains space between the gas, otherwise they would not be able to be compressed by gravity? To me, rather than a velocity producing big bang and gravity and expansion, having many layers contained within each other and expanding out makes a simpler system, and the layers visible in the plot in the original post nicely shows exponential expansion at different layers with different size objects between the layers that are expanding.

Comment: Atoms expanded first, there are many layers in atoms, the combination of all these layers of expansion at the small could disconnect atoms from each other, giving them properties we see, creating both particles and quantum mechanics. Now it is mainly just the biggest scale expanding as we see. The big bang might have been a good explanation before all this expansion, but now with all these discoveries having many layers of the universe contained within each other, each layer expanding to produce space, but not just the space between stars but also the space between atoms.